# ValueError: No I2C device at address: 0x29 (and others) with TSL2591 on raspberry pi zero W with pijuicezero

Tags: i2c, pi-zero-w, adafruit

I am trying to get the TSL2591 outputting values on a raspberry pi zero W with extended pins and a pijuice zero over it. The following code

```py
import board
import adafruit_tsl2591
import time

i2c = board.I2C()

while not i2c.try_lock():
    pass

try:
    while True:
        print(
            "I2C addresses found:",
            [hex(device_address) for device_address in i2c.scan()],
        )
        time.sleep(2)

finally:  # unlock the i2c bus when ctrl-c'ing out of the loop
    i2c.unlock()
```

works fine and shows the following output

```bash
I2C addresses found: ['0x14', '0x28', '0x29', '0x68']
I2C addresses found: ['0x14', '0x28', '0x29', '0x68']
I2C addresses found: ['0x14', '0x28', '0x29', '0x68']
I2C addresses found: ['0x14', '0x28', '0x29', '0x68']
```

However, when I run the code from the [installation instructions](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-tsl2591/python-circuitpython)

```py
import board
import adafruit_tsl2591
import time

i2c = board.I2C()
sensor = adafruit_tsl2591.TSL2591(i2c)
```

there is a stream of errors

```bash
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/.virtualenvs/lightsensor/lib/python3.9/site-packages/adafruit_bus_device/i2c_device.py", line 175, in __probe_for_device
    self.i2c.writeto(self.device_address, b"")
  File "/home/pi/.virtualenvs/lightsensor/lib/python3.9/site-packages/busio.py", line 196, in writeto
    return self._i2c.writeto(address, buffer, stop=stop)
  File "/home/pi/.virtualenvs/lightsensor/lib/python3.9/site-packages/adafruit_blinka/microcontroller/generic_linux/i2c.py", line 52, in writeto
    self._i2c_bus.write_bytes(address, buffer[start:end])
  File "/home/pi/.virtualenvs/lightsensor/lib/python3.9/site-packages/Adafruit_PureIO/smbus.py", line 303, in write_bytes
    self._device.write(buf)
OSError: [Errno 121] Remote I/O error

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/.virtualenvs/lightsensor/lib/python3.9/site-packages/adafruit_bus_device/i2c_device.py", line 181, in __probe_for_device
    self.i2c.readfrom_into(self.device_address, result)
  File "/home/pi/.virtualenvs/lightsensor/lib/python3.9/site-packages/busio.py", line 186, in readfrom_into
    return self._i2c.readfrom_into(address, buffer, stop=stop)
  File "/home/pi/.virtualenvs/lightsensor/lib/python3.9/site-packages/adafruit_blinka/microcontroller/generic_linux/i2c.py", line 59, in readfrom_into
    readin = self._i2c_bus.read_bytes(address, end - start)
  File "/home/pi/.virtualenvs/lightsensor/lib/python3.9/site-packages/Adafruit_PureIO/smbus.py", line 170, in read_bytes
    return self._device.read(number)
OSError: [Errno 121] Remote I/O error

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/init_tsl2591.py", line 6, in <module>
    sensor = adafruit_tsl2591.TSL2591(i2c)
  File "/home/pi/.virtualenvs/lightsensor/lib/python3.9/site-packages/adafruit_tsl2591.py", line 129, in __init__
    self._device = i2c_device.I2CDevice(i2c, address)
  File "/home/pi/.virtualenvs/lightsensor/lib/python3.9/site-packages/adafruit_bus_device/i2c_device.py", line 62, in __init__
    self.__probe_for_device()
  File "/home/pi/.virtualenvs/lightsensor/lib/python3.9/site-packages/adafruit_bus_device/i2c_device.py", line 184, in __probe_for_device
    raise ValueError("No I2C device at address: 0x%x" % self.device_address)
ValueError: No I2C device at address: 0x29
```

I've double checked the connections, and even used a multimeter to test the connectivity of the jumper wires: all okay. The hardware setup is shown below
[image][image][image][image]

Any thoughts about why I am not able to read the sensor/other things to test? Thanks.

Comment: why the downvote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, my issue was that the GND gpio pin was connected wrongly to GPIO17 (11) instead of GND (9) as shown [here](https://www.softwaresamurai.org/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/rpiZ-GPIO.png)